# Rails 3 - render partial js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple search form that looks something like:

*app/views/search/index.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @search, :as => :search, :remote => true, :url => {:action => "query"}, :html => {:id => 'search-form'} do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %

<div id="search-results"></div>
```

*app/controllers/search_controller.rb*

```
def index
  @search = SearchCriteria.new
end

def query
  @search = SearchCriteria.new(params[:search])

      # otherwise, perform search...
  @summaries = do_search @search
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I then have a js.erb template:
*app/views/search/_query.js.erb*

```
$('#search-results').update("<%= escape_javascript(render(@summaries)) %>");
```

However, I don't see anything being put into the 'search-results' div. Do I need some sort of template in order to render "@summaries"? If so, what would it be named and where would I place it (i.e. app/views/search?) (i am using jquery and rails 3)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose jQuery has an `.update` method. Try `.html`? Does Firebug throw any error in the console?

Comment: I switched to .html, no difference. what is "render(@summaries)" going to render? I'm guessing I'm missing a view or partial for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should rename your template file:

```
app/views/search/_query.js.erb => *app/views/search/query.js.erb
```

underscore is unnecessary

Comment: Yes, that helps. I then updated query.js.erb to do this:

    $('#search-results').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'summaries')) %>");

And I then created a app/views/search/_summaries.html.erb

Comment: Hi , I want to know what does this mean : "rails can render js in erb file " ?  Does this mean "ujs" ?